# why this code doesn't work? i need to take a string and a number and print the string backwards, and also for each char i need to move it n times

Tags: c, pointers

so if the string is 'abc' and n=1 i will print: 'dcb'.
here is the code. i have to use pointers because i can't use [].
so when i try to run it it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't print anything.
so if can find the problem i will be very thankful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void decrypt(char cipher[], int n);

int main(void)
{

    //Write your code here...
    char a[] = "abcde";
    
    decrypt(a, 1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void decrypt(char cipher[], int n)
{
    int len = strlen(cipher)
    char* p = cipher + len-1;
    for (p; p >= arr; p--)
    {
        (*p) += n;
        if ((*p) > 122)
        {
            (*p) = ((*p) % 122) + 97;
        }
        printf("%c ", *p);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is arr in decrypt()?

Comment: The code needs a semicolon after `strlen(cipher)` and I assume by `arr` you mean `cipher`. When I change that, it works for me and it doesn't even compile before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are accessing somewhere in memory that you shouldn't :)
This worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void decrypt(char cipher[], int n);

int main(void)
{

    //Write your code here...
    char a[] = "abc";
    
    decrypt(a, 1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void decrypt(char cipher[], int n)
{
    int len = strlen(cipher);
    char* p = cipher + len;
    for (int i = len; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        (*p) += n;
        if ((*p) > 122)
        {
            (*p) = ((*p) % 122) + 97;
        }
        printf("%c ", *(p--));
    }
}
```